# what java.net.preferIPv4Stack actually does and what kind of side effect it might have?

Tags: java, ubuntu, networking, ipv6

In Ubuntu(OS), What `java.net.preferIPv4Stack` actually does and what kind of side effect it might have?

According to the Java documentation,

> If IPv6 is available on the operating system, the underlying native
>   socket will be an IPv6 socket.

For example, if java program is connecting to some other server which does not have IPv6 does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It [causes the underlying native socket to be an IPv4 socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html). It doesn't help in the situation you mention. It does help to resolve certain bugs.

Comment: @EJP- You should continue writing these answers, some dumbasses are found everywhere who ignorantly downvotes these kinda answers. An upvote(+1) for you. I found it very helpful to visualise.

Comment: @shekhar Thanks. Downvotes like this should be worn with pride, like campaign medals. But we're not obliged to be unfailingly courteous about them ;-)